# Ubuntu 14.04 sendEmail issue: invalid SSL_version specified at /usr/share/perl5/IO/Socket/SSL.pm

Tags: debian, amazon-web-services, ubuntu-14.04

Despite finding other posts about this online, I cannot seem to get a resolution for our setup. We are using **Ubuntu 14.04 on AWS**. All I need this server to do is send an email (with a .PDF attachment) via ZOHO's mail server. The problem is that ZOHO's mail server requires SSL, there's no way around it. This is apparently a known bug in Debian: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=679911 However, I can't find a consensus on how to fix it, the Debian bug page just says to not use SSL, which isn't possible for the business since we're using ZOHO.

We have been using a Linux Mint 17.3 VM for this task, so I know for a fact it is possible, but that particular VM cannot be used for this any longer (for reasons I won't go into).

Can someone please tell me what edits to make with Nano to fix this and to what files? I apologize, but my Linux skills are still in development, so please be kind and assist me (I am a Windows SysAdmin mostly). Thank you.

Comment: Have you installed any relevant updates?

Comment: Thanks, Michael. Negative, the server is newly deployed as of yesterday.

Comment: Well then, you know what to do.

Comment: I tried this: 'sudo apt-get update && upgrade'  
...but it did not work. I then tried 'sudo apt-get update' and 'sudo apt-get upgrade' separately, but that did not work either.

Comment: I manually updated sendEmail from v1.55 to v1.56 and that didn't work either.

Comment: Still stuck here. Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a resolution by deleting this faulty AWS instance and deploying a new one, again of Ubuntu Server 14.04, only this time I followed these instructions to get sendEmail going: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1127478

```
sudo apt-get install sendemail  
sudo apt-get install libio-socket-ssl-perl
```